# I want to remove the white background from and image not inside just outside the colored pixels using convert command in terminal

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sed, imagemagick

I've image an [image](https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-xSUqqHvsoaE/YYTv4911C_I/AAAAAAAADhc/N-QMzOa5Y5Mo3pTsHazfBJv8cpzadpHPQCLcBGAsYHQ/s860/imoji.png) with white background. I used command to make it transparent

```
convert imoji.png -fuzz 20% -transparent white result.png
```

I got the [result.png](https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-dNfq8OiACCs/YYTxZF_4DaI/AAAAAAAADhk/Iug6KhDDZjkMbu--enUQ01YYX4JNvGHtACLcBGAsYHQ/s860/result.png). The command has removed pixels inside the emoji and some other parts. I need it to be something like [this](https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-2jPsP4_h3wA/YYT0woYYPlI/AAAAAAAADh0/DP-CBz3nccYCCXJJpTRLzlqnOOlbe6XnwCLcBGAsYHQ/s810/FINAL.png). I made it using photoshop by reducing the tolerance of the magic wand tool. Help me to do the same using the convert command in the terminal. I reduced the -fuzz 20 to 1% still not getting the result.

Answer (score 4):

Use flood fill from the top left corner of the image in ImageMagick.

```
convert imoji.png -fuzz 20% -fill none -draw "matte 0,0 floodfill" result.png
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I'm new here what can I do for you to get something lime popularity or something. Must reply.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your question

Comment: How can I award you for this help? I'm new here I need to kno.

Comment: Thanks. You can up vote my answer using the upper gray triangle at the top left side where it current has a 0 between them. Just click the top gray triangle

Comment: Done  **pressed**.

Comment: If you clicked the correct triangle, it does not show an up-vote. The number (currently 0) should go to 1, if you did it correctly.

Comment: I don't know I'm new here.

Comment: At the top left corner of my answer there is a gray triangle pointing up. Below that is a 0. Below that is a gray triangle pointing down. Click the upward pointing triangle and the 0 should change to a 1.

Answer (score 0):

In the updated ImageMagick 7.1.1-20 version, matte is no longer supported as a command. Instead, use alpha:

```
convert imoji.png -fuzz 20% -fill none -draw "alpha 0,0 floodfill" result.png
```

You can install ImageMagick as follows:

##### Mac

```
brew install imagemagick
```

##### Ubuntu linux

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```